# Fetch and insert value of property from model at runtime

Tags: ios, swift

```
struct Person {
    let firstName: String?
    let lastName: String?
    let age: Int?
}
```

I have a `UILabel` inside which I have to insert a value which can be either of these properties.

At runtime, I will receive a JSON response inside which I will have a key whose value will be the **name of either one of these properties** say `firstName` or `lastName` or any other value like

{
  "value":"firstName"
}

Now I will check this `value`'s value (Inside JSON) and verify if this exists inside the model `Person` and if it does(which it always will as we will design the JSON that way), will insert the value for that property (`firstName` in our case)

Now one way I can think of is putting a lot of `if-else` and check the `value`'s value inside the JSON and then take the value from model and all but it's a lot of boiler plate code.

Is there some other way to achieve the same ?

Comment: *as we will design the JSON that way*. Why? That's unnecessarily cumbersome. And why are all struct members optional? In real life every person has at least a first name and an age.

Comment: @vadian Person is just an example, there can be a lot of values that may or may not be present . The main thing is I want to achieve this functionality

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to change your JSON something like:

```
{
    "firstName":"ABC",
    "lastName":nil,
    "age":nil
}
```

And only render the non-nil values on your UI.